# Listen to reactive() invalidation in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

is there an exposed (maybe even non-exposed) function in shiny that would tell me when a reactive got invalidated? Draft of example:

ui.R

```
selectInput('select', ...)
```

server.R

```
myfunc <- reactive({ ... input$select ... })

output$listen <- textOutput({
   valid_flag <- ???(myfunc)
   paste('This function is', valid_flag)
})
```

The `???()` function would give me the information if the reactive is valid or invalidated.

Comment: Im reading this over and over and im not 100% clear on the questions:

is this what you want?

 `valid_flag <- "Done"; message(paste('This function is', valid_flag)`)

Comment: So in shiny you have the reactive stack that flushes every time when any of the dependencies change and all the reactives get invalidated. I would like to have a function that can read this state - if a reactive object is valid or invalidated.

Comment: use `myfunc()` to access it and not just `myfunc`

Comment: Well, I do not want to access it, I want to find out its state from the reactive stack perspective. The return value is something different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might have actually found the solution after browsing the shiny package code. The object of class `reactive` is an S3 object but the reactivity mechanism is "hidden" in `attr(object, "observable")` which is R6 class. The solution of my problem above would be:

```
myfunc <- reactive({ ... input$select ... })

output$listen <- textOutput({
   valid_flag <- attr(myfunc, "observable")$.invalidated
   paste('This function is invalidated:', valid_flag)
})
```

The example might not be the best (I am still not sure if `attr(myfunc, "observable")` acts as a reactive object but I am using it in a different context - not to be printed out in a reactive way but rather to inform other parts of code about the status of the reactive stack.

Comment: Very interesting! I'm using your approach to update the text in an action button with relevant inputs have been invalidated. I'm still working to figure out how to best apply this in some of my apps though. Have you posted anything online I could take a look at (e.g., on github)?